# Tile notification for windows phone - invalid XML payload -

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-8, push-notification, mpns

I send two push notifications a toast and a tile (just a count)

the toast gets received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification"><wp:Toast><wp:Text1></wp:Text1><wp:Text2>asdf</wp:Text2><wp:Param></wp:Param></wp:Toast></wp:Notification>
```

the tile does not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification"><wp:Tile><wp:BackgroundImage></wp:BackgroundImage><wp:Count>122</wp:Count><wp:Title></wp:Title><wp:BackBackgroundImage></wp:BackBackgroundImage><wp:BackTitle></wp:BackTitle><wp:BackContent></wp:BackContent></wp:Tile></wp:Notification>
```

This is the xml i provide and I keep getting **format errors**. Is there something wrong in the format?

Comment: What's the os version of your  target device? Some features are only available from 7.5 version

Answer (score 1):

Your tile format should be like

```
 string tileMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                    "<wp:Tile>" +
                      "<wp:BackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackgroundImage>" +
                      "<wp:Count>" + TextBoxCount.Text + "</wp:Count>" +
                      "<wp:Title>" + TextBoxTitle.Text + "</wp:Title>" +
                      "<wp:BackBackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackBackgroundImage>" +
                      "<wp:BackTitle>" + TextBoxBackTitle.Text + "</wp:BackTitle>" +
                      "<wp:BackContent>" + TextBoxBackContent.Text + "</wp:BackContent>" +
                   "</wp:Tile> " +
                "</wp:Notification>";
```

Sending tile notification code.It will work for me. If any query than let me know

```
 protected void ButtonSendTile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the Uri that the Microsoft Push Notification Service returns to the Push Client when creating a notification channel.
                // Normally, a web service would listen for Uri's coming from the web client and maintain a list of Uri's to send
                // notifications out to.
                string subscriptionUri = TextBoxUri.Text.ToString();


                HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

                // We will create a HTTPWebRequest that posts the tile notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
                // HTTP POST is the only allowed method to send the notification.
                sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

                // The optional custom header X-MessageID uniquely identifies a notification message. 
                // If it is present, the // same value is returned in the notification response. It must be a string that contains a UUID.
                // sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", "<UUID>");

                // Create the tile message.
                string tileMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                    "<wp:Tile>" +
                      "<wp:BackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackgroundImage>" +
                      "<wp:Count>" + TextBoxCount.Text + "</wp:Count>" +
                      "<wp:Title>" + TextBoxTitle.Text + "</wp:Title>" +
                      "<wp:BackBackgroundImage>" + TextBoxBackBackgroundImage.Text + "</wp:BackBackgroundImage>" +
                      "<wp:BackTitle>" + TextBoxBackTitle.Text + "</wp:BackTitle>" +
                      "<wp:BackContent>" + TextBoxBackContent.Text + "</wp:BackContent>" +
                   "</wp:Tile> " +
                "</wp:Notification>";


                // Sets the notification payload to send.
                byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(tileMessage);

                // Sets the web request content length.
                sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
                sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
                sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "token");
                sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "1");


                using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
                }

                // Send the notification and get the response.
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
                string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
                string notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
                string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

                // Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
                // Normally, error handling code would be here.  In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
                // notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
                TextBoxResponse.Text = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TextBoxResponse.Text = "Exception caught sending update: " + ex.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: @Bran Gi:just copy and past in this code in to your send tile button click

Comment: did exactly the same, however my background image didn't show up. is there anything that i need to watch out for?

Comment: @LHZ: what you are passing on background image parameter?

Comment: you have to pass only name when you send back ground image and this image is store in your project folder

Comment: i passed the url of a background image hosted in the internet.

Comment: JUST TRY TO PASS NAME OF IMAGE THAT IS IN YOUR PROJECT (i.e BLUE.JPEG ) than place this image in your project folder

Comment: my app requires it to be dynamic